# How to adapt the Chain of Responsibility pattern to pass state

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm looking for a design that satisfies the following requirements:

1. There is a single, publicly-visible object that has the following interface:

   ```
   class Whatever
   {
       Whatever& GetIntstance();

       void UpdateData1(POD d1); // POD: Plain old datatype
       void UpdateData2(POD d2);
       // ...
       void UpdateDataN(POD dN);

       bool Question1();
       bool Question2();
       // ...
       bool QuestionM();
   }
   ```

Where `void UpdateDataX(POD dX) (1 <= X <= N)` sets some internal state.

Where `bool QuestionY() (1 <= Y <= M)` asks a yes/no question and is computed from internal state.

2. The Whatever instance may not know how to answer all Questions.  In the case that it does not know how to answer a question, it needs to delegate the responsibility.
3. Different questions may have different delegates.
4. A delegate may have a delegate.
5. When delegating a question, an object needs to let a delegate have read-access to its state and the state of anything that delegated to it.
6. A delegate may take a long time to answer a question (don't ask why), so its answer may be cached.  This means that the delegate needs to be notified if state, on which it is dependent, changes.  This also means that delegates need to be notified on a call to UpdateDataX.

Assume that the tree structure (DAG structure, or whatever structure) of delegates is fixed after it is constructed.

Comment: This question is a little broad for stack overflow, could you narrow your problem down to a more specific question?

Comment: This looks a bit like a XY question. It's unclear what your issue actually is - the class Whatever looks sort of fine already - (and you just need to implement the delegates).

Comment: @darune this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @AlanBirtles could you explain why you think this question is broad?  It has clearly satisfiable requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to solve this problem would be:

1. Extract the mutable state into a separate model object that allows delegates to attach update listeners to it (observer pattern)
2. When the delegates are constructed (probably by `Whatever`), each one is passed the model object and whatever other delegates (or anything else) it depends on (constructor dependency injection)
3. If a delegate requires a cache, then it would implement/create that cache itself (single responsibility principle).

Since you're working in C++, it's also important to emphasize the you should use RAII.  Because of all the life cycle relationships between objects, you'll probably hold onto the model and delegates with `shared_ptr`.